# Distributing candy to two people

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking that for 30 of the candies they have two choices and the other 30 have 1 choice, so it would but 30*2+30=90, but that was wrong, can somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that choosing $30$ candies for one person gives the second person no choice but to take what's left. So it is sufficient to count number of ways to pick $30$ candies. Using stars and bars, that number is:$$\binom{30+3-1}{3-1} - 3\binom{10 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1}=\binom{32}{2} - 3\binom{12}{2} =298$$
Here the first term is the number of ways to pick $30$ candies from $3$ types of candies if supply of each type is unlimited. The second term represent overcounting (we only have $20$ candies of each type)

Answer (score 1):

A distribution is completely determined by deciding which candies to give to the younger of the two people since the older one must receive the remaining candies.

Let $c$, $g$, and $l$ represent the number of candies given to the younger of the two people.  Then
$$c + g + l = 30 \tag{1}$$
where $c, g, l$ are nonnegative integers $c \leq 20$, $g \leq 20$, and $l \leq 20$.

If we ignore those restrictions for the moment, a particular solution of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of two addition signs in a row of $30$ ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $c = 10$, $g = 0$, and $l = 20$, while
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $c = g = l = 10$.  The number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways we can insert two addition signs in a row of $30$ ones, which is
$$\binom{30 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{32}{2}$$
From these, we must subtract those cases in which at least one of the numbers exceeds $20$.  Observe that at most one of the numbers can exceed $20$ since $2 \cdot 21 = 42 > 30$.

Suppose $c > 20$.  Since $c$ is an integer, $c \geq 21$.  Let $c' = c - 21$. Then $c'$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substituting $c' + 21$ for $c$ in equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
c' + 21 + g + l & = 30\\
c' + g + l & = 9 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integer with 
$$\binom{9 + 3 - 1}{3 - 1} = \binom{11}{2}$$
solutions.  By symmetry, there are the same number of solutions of equation 1 in which $g > 20$ or $l > 20$.  Hence, there are 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{11}{2}$$
solutions of equation that violate at least one of the restrictions $c \leq 20$, $g \leq 20$, or $l \geq 20$.

Hence, the number of ways to distribute $20$ chocolates, $20$ gummy bears, and $20$ lemon drops to two people so that each person receives $30$ candies is
$$\binom{32}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{11}{2}$$